# Lume Static Site Generator and Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a Lume project with a _data folder containing some calls to Firestore which ends up with an array:

Setup:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Current array after calling firestore:

```
[
  { imageURLs:[{id: string}], foo, bar... },
  ...
]
```

Now I need to call a function on firebase storage to get the image, something along the lines of:
`await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'images/' + id));`

Calling getDownloadURL however will return `Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`.

How do I solve this?

I have tried to see if Firebase admin could help but as this is not a Node environment (these calls happen inside a _data file in Lume) I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by importing the following from Deno:
`import "https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.1.0/mod.ts";`